# git delete changes in a commit?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, rebase

I had to rebase a commit where a single directory was supposed to be changed.

Now when I see latest changes in gitlab, there are dozens of directories that appear as changed in the branch.

I now need to somehow keep the changes in the directory that I want to keep only, and omit everything else. In other words I need to create a new commit where the only changes are the changes to the current relevant directory, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You could make the necessary changes and commit them just like normal. Or do you want to modify existing commits?

Comment: I need the commits in the remote itself to not show these changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify existing commits, you can use interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i <starting commit or branch>
```

This command will open a text editor with a list of commits. For each commit, you can provide an action to perform. The action defaults to "pick". You probably want to use "edit" here. After you save the file and close the editor, the rebase begins. When git encounters a commit you choose to edit, it stops the rebase. You can perform whatever git commands you want at this point. For example, you can do

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~
```

Now edit the files as you see fit and make a commit. When you finish

```
git rebase --continue
```

Rinse and repeat as necessary.

For more details see `git help rebase`. Note that rebasing merge commits does not preserve the merges by default. Instead it will rebase the individual commits in both histories.